# Effective degrees of freedom for residual variance in ridge regression

Tags: variance, ridge-regression, degrees-of-freedom

The definition of the effective degrees of freedom (*dof*) in Ridge Regression via the trace of the "hat matrix" is well known (see e.g. Hastie and Tibshirani's *Generalized Additive Models*).
But it seems less clear/widely published whether one should use this *dof* value for the computation of the residual variance $\widehat{\sigma}_u^2$.
Also, the common software implementations of Ridge regressions (e.g. `glmnet` in R, `Ridge` in sklearn) do not compute $\widehat{\sigma}_u^2$ by default.

Is there a clear and formally justified consensus on this ?

Comment: N-1-p where p is the  effective degrees of freedom for the whole model and no penalization is done on the intercept.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had assumed that would be the case (to just replace n-k-1 (k=num of coefficients) with n-p-1 ) but was doubtful because (i) this is not clearly communicated in the same sources that define the effective dof and (ii) most software implementations do not compute the residual variance.

Comment: See the maximum likelihood chapter in my text Regression Modeling Strategies or the brief version of it in https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/mle